# rails reference to html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

this is probably simple problem, but I am not sure how to do this.
I have MVC of posts(created with scaffold), everything works fine. But I want to create for example About page, but I need it to be .html.erb not just static page, so I cannot have it in public folder. So I created file in app/views/posts/about.html.erb, but when I link to page I got no routes error.

routes.rb

```
  resources :posts do
    get :about 
  end
```

posts_controller

```
def about
   @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

What should I do to be able to link to this html erb like this ?

```
<a href="about.html.erb"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i>About</a>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that problem was with my routes.rb when I used 
    get 'about' => 'posts#about'
It is working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

try href="posts/about". it will help)

Comment: Please expand. Some information about what was wrong and why "posts/about" will actually be routed to the correct `erb` is in order.

Comment: resoucres with block also make namespace. in your case namespace is 'posts'.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can define your route as

```
resources :posts do
   collection do
    get :about
   end
end
```